# I just ordered 70/10 internet service, and need a new router I think?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Before I had 25/5 service and the N standard router did just fine. Now it doesn't do the job. Online speedtest reads at 82 so I have the line. But my laptop is getting less than 30 in my room. My laptop has the following WiFi card: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-advanced-n-6205.html

What is this talk about 2.4 and 5GHz? Can my laptop be connected at once over both bands? And would that let me use the full 70Mb over Wi-Fi?

Comment: What router do you have now?  Are there other devices that may be using bandwidth?  Are there possibly conflicting WiFi devices nearby?

Comment: Hmm it could distance as well. When I sit beside the router (n router, jensen model white one with no external antenna) I get about 50Mb on speedtest.net.

Comment: what router are you using and how is it configured, what encryption are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to both 2,4 GHz and 5GHz your WiFi card supports both, the question is which standard and frequency does you router/wirelles access point work.

You are probably on 802.11g standard which has the speed up to 54 mbps but will in most cases work with less speed (depending on the distance from AP and number of devices on it)

You can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#endnote_80211ns_sgiB1) to see more about differences between standards

If you router is set to 802.11n, some claim that 802.11n works slower in mixed mode (see the thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/430185/does-a-wireless-n-802-11n-network-have-poor-performance-when-in-b-g-mixed-mo)). The claims are following

- Just putting the AP to mixed mode slows the speed
- The speed gets slow down only if b clients are connected
- The speed slows down if b or g clients are connected
- The speed slows down not based on mixed protocol but encryption (if you use WEP,WPA or mixed WPA/WPA2 encryption), actually this isn't just a claim [Intel states that data rate will not exceed 54 Mbps when WEP or TKIP encryption is configured](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/4965agn/sb/cs-025643.htm), it's 802.11n cards will fall down to 802.11g standard, because 802.11n prohibits using wep or tkip on networks, so if both your client and AP are N check if it's configured to use WPA2

Comment: 802.11n allows to take up large parts 2.4 GHz ISM spectrum for transfer rates around 150 Mb/s per antenna, there is no requirement to use the 5 GHz frequencies.

Comment: -1. You're spreading one falsehood that you can't do 802.11n in 2.4GHz, a second falsehood that N is only 150mbps in 5GHz, and a third falsehood that enabling mixed G/N mode slows down the N clients. His Intel 6205 wireless card is 2x2:2 N, HT40 in either band, so it can do 300 mbps in either band. Please either delete your answer or read up on 802.11n and fix it.

Comment: I know 802.11n works with both 2,4 and 5 GHz, I shaped the answer wrong. About the mixed mode, the opinions seem to differ on both sides. The general recommendation is to have 802.11n clients on 5GHz and old b/g clients on 2,4 GHz so there is less interference